# How to set horizontal or vertical alignment Text in PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, alignment, text-alignment

i am generating a PDF, and i am outputting some text, e.g.:

```
BT
  /F1 7 Tf
  586 406 Td
  (Date Shipped:) Tj
ET
```

A quick primer on the [PDF programming language](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

- `BT`:  *begin text block*
- `/F1 7 Tf`: *Select font #`1` (which in my case is Helvetica), and use font size of `7` point*
- `586 406 Td` *Move the current location to (x=`586` pt, y=`406` pt)*
- `(Date Shipped:) Tj`: *Render the text `Date Shipped:`*
- `ET`: *end text block*

That text is now always rendered at location (586,406), with the **bottom left** of the text block at that location:

[image]

What i **want** is that point to define the **top center** point:

[image]

Because i do not know the *size* of the rendered text; i cannot simply fudge things up/down/left/right to try to make up for it.

How can i indicate in a PDF some text's *"alignment"*?

Comment: You cannot. PDF producing software needs to know the font metrics to produce formatted output. As you know that you selected Helvetica at size 7 and you also know the current character and word spacing values, you can easily calculate the size of the rendered text. You may want to read the PDF specification (made available [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)), especially the chapter on text rendering.

Comment: The font metrics of the standard 14 fonts are available [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/wwdistiller.html).

Comment: @mkl Put *"You can't"* in the form of an answer: and you got yourself an accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. PDF producing software needs to know the font metrics to produce formatted output.

As you know that you selected Helvetica at size 7 and you also know the current character and word spacing values, you can easily calculate the size of the rendered text.

The font metrics of the standard 14 fonts are available [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/wwdistiller.html).

You may want to read the PDF specification (made available [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)), especially the chapter on text rendering.

Comment: i don't know the font metrics when they are fonts not in that list (e.g. Arial). Accepted as *not possible*.

Comment: Metrics of other fonts require that you parse three font files.

Comment: In the pdf specification linked in question I found something about layout attributes (do search on "TextAlign") but in my understanding it is only something like comment and does not change the way the text is rendered on page, but provides the tips to editing / converting software.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jakub That are *Layout Attributes,* cf. section 14.8.5.4. There you'll also find the **NOTE *The intent is that these parameters can be used to reflow the content or export it to some other document format with at least basic styling preserved*.** Thus, your assumption that they are *tips to editing / converting software* is correct.